# Bottom of text being cut off

Tags: html, css

im not sure why this is happening, but for some reason a text block im trying to create before images keeps getting cut off at some arbirtrary height by the images after the text box:

i have my text box (the lorem ipsum) in a div call textblock , and my images are each in seperate container divs so i can apply the caption on top.  i dont quite understand why the text is being cut off at a random height and the images arent just starting once the text block is complete.  the height the images start at seems to be connected to the width of the text block tho.

i can try to post the code here but it should all be in the source there.  please keep in mind im not an html or css expert.  im looking to create a very simple website, but for some reason this basic thing is not working the way i want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is getting cut because `top :80px` is given to class .textblock but not for .container class.  Try giving margin-top:80px instead of top.

Try below `CSS`

```
.textblock {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    left: 200px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}
```